# Automatic reshape of seaborn.heatmap with available dataframe rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframa as below:

```
       Symbol  Change  Yrows  Xcols
0  ADANIPORTS    7.15      1      1
1  BAJAJ-AUTO    3.04      1      2
2  HINDUNILVR    3.00      1      3
3         M&M   -2.69      2      1
4         UPL   -2.92      2      2
5        NTPC   -3.15      2      3
6    JSWSTEEL   -3.30      3      1
7   COALINDIA   -3.38      3      2
8        ONGC   -3.48      3      3
```

Here my Dataframe consists of 9 rows hence below code runs fine. But when dataframe size reduces to 8 it gives reshape error.

I need help on below 2 conditions.

1. I want to plot the heat map without that 9th row when not available.
2. How to automatically reshape of HeatMap table with available data of dataframe.

My Code as below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Heatmap_data.csv")
Yrows = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
Xcols = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
df = df.assign(Yrows=Yrows, Xcols=Xcols)

symbol = ((np.asarray(df['Symbol'])).reshape(3, 3))
perchange = ((np.asarray(df['Change'])).reshape(3, 3))

result = df.pivot(index='Yrows', columns='Xcols', values='Change')
labels = (np.asarray(["{0} \n {1:.2f}%".format(symb, value) for symb, value in zip(symbol.flatten(), perchange.flatten())])).reshape(3, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 7))
title = "Heat Map"
plt.title(title, fontsize=18)
ttl = ax.title
ttl.set_position([0.5, 1.05])
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.axis('off')
sns.heatmap(result, annot=labels, fmt="", cmap='RdYlGn', linewidths=0.40, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

I want my desired out put with dataframe of 8 rows as below:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work out of the box if you use pandas to reshape. This is because a pandas pivot will insert `NaN` values on missing entries, whereas numpy’s  `reshape` method does not allow to reshape if there are not enough values (i.e. you can’t reshape an array of 8 elements into a 3x3 table).

Let’s try this with 8 entries:

```
>>> df
       Symbol  Change
0  ADANIPORTS    7.15
1  BAJAJ-AUTO    3.04
2  HINDUNILVR    3.00
3         M&M   -2.69
4         UPL   -2.92
5        NTPC   -3.15
6    JSWSTEEL   -3.30
7   COALINDIA   -3.38
```

First, assign rows and columns as you did, so we can use `pivot` to make the 2D arrays:

```
>>> df = df.assign(row = np.arange(len(df)) // 3, col = np.arange(len(df)) % 3)
>>> df
       Symbol  Change  row  col
0  ADANIPORTS    7.15    0    0
1  BAJAJ-AUTO    3.04    0    1
2  HINDUNILVR    3.00    0    2
3         M&M   -2.69    1    0
4         UPL   -2.92    1    1
5        NTPC   -3.15    1    2
6    JSWSTEEL   -3.30    2    0
7   COALINDIA   -3.38    2    1
>>> change = df.pivot('row', 'col', 'Change')
>>> change
col     0     1     2
row                  
0    7.15  3.04  3.00
1   -2.69 -2.92 -3.15
2   -3.30 -3.38   NaN
```

For labels, let’s generate them from the series first and them pivot them in the same way:

```
>>> df['Label'] = df['Symbol'].str.cat(df['Change'].apply('{:.2f}%'.format), sep='\n')
>>> labels = df.pivot('row', 'col', 'Label')
>>> labels
col                  0                  1                  2
row                                                         
0    ADANIPORTS\n7.15%  BAJAJ-AUTO\n3.04%  HINDUNILVR\n3.00%
1          M&M\n-2.69%        UPL\n-2.92%       NTPC\n-3.15%
2     JSWSTEEL\n-3.30%  COALINDIA\n-3.38%                NaN
```

Now we can use your plot call and it all works as intended:

```
>>> sns.heatmap(change, annot=symbol, fmt='', cmap='RdYlGn', linewidths=0.40)
```

[image: seaborn heatmap]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Is there any way to bold few selected stocks with their percentage value ?